# Why is Lua returning an empty table in this code?

Tags: c++, lua

edit:
As I commented before, my problem is I can't create a table in C which uses strings as keys. I made a quick test program which demonstrates the problem I'm having:

Here is the C++ part of it:

```
#include <lua.hpp>
#include <String.h>

BString
LuaTypeToString(lua_State *L, int index, int type)
{
    BString out;
    switch (type)
    {
        case LUA_TSTRING:
        {
            out << "'" << lua_tostring(L, index) << "'";
            break;
        }
        case LUA_TBOOLEAN:
        {
            out << (lua_toboolean(L, index) ? "true" : "false");
            break;
        }
        case LUA_TNUMBER:
        {
            out << (float)lua_tonumber(L, index);
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            out << lua_typename(L, type);
            break;
        }
    }
    return out;
}


void
DumpLuaTable(lua_State *L, int tableIndex)
{
    lua_pushnil(L);
    printf("\t{ ");
    while (lua_next(L, tableIndex) != 0)
    {
        BString keyString = lua_tostring(L, -2);

        BString valueString;
        int type = lua_type(L, -1);
        if (type == LUA_TTABLE)
            DumpLuaTable(L, lua_gettop(L));
        else
            valueString = LuaTypeToString(L, -1, type);

        printf("%s=%s,",
            keyString.String(),
            valueString.String());
        lua_pop(L, 1);

        if (lua_isnumber(L, -1))
        {
            lua_pop(L, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    printf(" }");
}


void
DumpLuaStack(lua_State *L)
{
    printf("DumpLuaStack:\n");
    int top = lua_gettop(L);
    for (int i = 1; i <= top; i++)
    {
        int type = lua_type(L, i);
        if (type == LUA_TTABLE)
            DumpLuaTable(L, i);
        else
            printf("\t%s  ", LuaTypeToString(L, i, type).String());
    }
    printf("\n");
}



static
int
ReturnTable(lua_State *L)
{
    lua_newtable(L);
    lua_pushnumber(L, 3.14);
    lua_pushstring(L, "1");
    lua_settable(L, -3);

    DumpLuaStack(L);

    return 1;
}


int
main(void)
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    lua_pushcfunction(L, ReturnTable);
    lua_setglobal(L, "ReturnTable");

    int status = luaL_dofile(L, "luatest.lua");
    if (status)
        printf("Status = %d: %s\n", status, lua_tostring(L, -1));

    lua_close(L);

    return status;
}
```

And the Lua part of it:

```
function DumpTable(table)
    print("LuaDumpTable")
    local out = "\t"
    if #table > 0 then
        for i, v in ipairs(table) do
          out = out .. i .. "=" .. v .. " "
        end
        print(out)
    else
        print("\tEmpty table")
    end
end

value = ReturnTable()
if (type(value) == "table") then
    DumpTable(value)
else
    print(type(value))
end
```

The code as it is works without problem -- the Lua script prints out what you would expect. Change the line which pushes 3.14 to the stack to, say, `lua_pushstring(L, "foo");` and all I get is an empty table on the Lua side. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to show the Lua code that you use to determine that the table is empty. Everything you've shown here seems correct.

Comment: Did you read B Mitch's comment? Did you see how he wasn't using `#table` in his version of DumpTable? Did you see how he wasn't using `ipairs` and used `pairs` instead? Why don't you do that and see how it works.

Answer (score 5):

You're checking the table incorrectly in Lua:

```lua
if #table > 0 then
```

The `#table` is just telling you that the first unused integer in the table is 0.  When you have a string inserted into the table, it doesn't increment the count since it's not part of a continuous array, and you also can't process it with `ipairs`.  Just switch to using `pairs` and you should see `foo`:

```lua
function DumpTable(table)
    print("LuaDumpTable")
    local out = "\t"
    for i, v in pairs(table) do
      out = out .. i .. "=" .. v .. " "
    end
    print(out)
end
```

---

Older note, left as an fyi:

I doubt this would cause the issue, but for API's being called from Lua, you typically want to pop the input off of the stack.  So after the `lua_tonumber` call:

```c
int32 value = lua_tonumber(L, 1);

lua_pop(L, 1);

rgb_color c = ui_color((color_which)value);
```

Comment: While waiting for an answer, I stripped down what I was doing to a quick test project. I'm having problems returning a table which uses strings for keys.  I have to walk out the door in a second, but I'll post the revision when I get back.

Comment: *smacks forehead* Of course! I forgot about the # operator (and lua_objlen) only counting integer indices. I didn't know about the ipairs vs pairs thing, so thank you both *very* much for your time and patience. :)